# Why OOP is enforced in Java and C#?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented

In many other languages like C++ and Javascript, OOP is optional. Procedural code is ok. But in languages like Java and C#, OOP is somewhat enforced. Everything is to be a part of a class or an object. What are the benefits?

Comment: Consistency.  What more could there be?  Could you give some reasons why you think there are no benefits?

Comment: What do you mean it's enforced?  How so?

Comment: The class idiom is enforced, but don't worry, you can still produce crap-code that won't be OO in any way, if that floats your boat.

Comment: You can still have all your code in a single main method, I don't think this is OO in any way imaginable

Comment: "raise a doubt by asking clarifications of clear things"?  Sorry.  I'm not raising a doubt.  I'm asking what you think the "cost" is.  Somehow you appear to think there is no "benefit" to "OOP is enforced".  I can't understand why you'd ask this.  Please explain why you are asking.  It's not "doubt".  It's a question.  What do you mean?

Comment: If you're fond of the "static" keyword, C# can be just as procedural as javascript.

Comment: @S.Lott Sorry. The question came in mind from this question- http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49842/php-a-structural-or-oop-based-language

Comment: @haylem nails it. You're not forced to do OOP, you're forced to organize code in classes and methods. And that, I'd say, is a pretty annoying restriction.

Comment: @Gulshan: Please provide **your** explanation of what **you** want to know.  Clearly, you're worried about something you call "the benefits".  Please explain what **you** understand and what you want to know.

Comment: It is not "enforced". Just think of classes as of some limited form of modules and use `static`.

Comment: @haylem: Of course, not all designs are best expressed through object oriented principles. LINQ is a great example of a functional programming paradigm which gets the point across much better than equivalent object oriented constructs.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "OOP is enforced"? To me, it rather looks like OOP is pretty much impossible in Java and C#. (Of course, they are both Turing-complete, so *nothing* is really impossible. http://Redline.ST/ is an example of how to make Java support OOP: just write a Smalltalk VM in Java and write your code in Smalltalk. But I suppose that's not what you mean by "enforce OOP".)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I totally agree. When I say you can still produce crap code that won't be OO, it doesn't necessarily mean that all non-OO code is crap :) Just that you can always produce ugly stuff and break out from the paradigm "recommended" by and for your language of choice.

Comment: @Phobia: Procederal code isn't about having all code in a single method, is it? You divide it into diffent procedures, so the analogy would be to have all code in one big class, not one big method.

Comment: @user unknown yes you can do that too, sorry about the misstatement

Comment: Since when is the choice of programming paradigms either OOP or procedural?

Comment: @Eric Lippert Hope you will answer.

Comment: Gotta love how OOP is the scapegoat for every programmer's woes these days. I'm gung-ho functional these days myself, but the passionate hate of OOP is even more of a blind trend than OOP itself. I highly doubt that most people who rag on OOP lately can even explain its demerits with any confidence.

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka, there are so many elaborate and convincing explanations of why OOP is unfit for the majority of the problem domains, that there is no need to add anything else. It is not a trend, it is just a reckoning slowly getting into masses.

Comment: @SK-logic -- I suppose, but to me it still looks like people are overcompensating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both C# and Java are marked as languages known not for what they enable, but what they *disable*, in terms of the feature set they use. (C# less so these days with LINQ but that's a whole different can of worms) Both of these languages are designed such that it's more difficult to create bad designs, at the expense of some freedom to the programmer. Generally speaking, object oriented design produces more reusable and maintainable designs than non object oriented design. (Note: I say "generally" here -- some designs are of course more easily expressed using (for example) functional programming primitives) Therefore, OO is the default paradigm supported in these languages.

(Again C# is a bit of an oddball here because it supports functional programming style)

Comment: "more difficult to create bad designs"?  Not enough more difficult to make a difference.  Actually, I think they encourage bad designs, by preventing bad designs from doing anything obviously bad (like crashing), the naive programmer never knows that improvement is needed or possible.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not saying I think Java/C# have the right answer -- I'm saying that's what their design goals were. (I like working in C++ more than those languages, and it has very different design goals)

Comment: @Ben -- The languages are decidedly strongly typed so that they crash upon compilation on as many obvious errors as possible (e.g. function paths not returning values, switches without breaks etc.). They'll also crash upon array bounds being broken rather than just roll on the way C/C++ does. While there are obviously languages that are even more strict, I have no idea where you get the idea that these languages are designed not to make problems obvious -- because the exact opposite is true.

Comment: @Rei: Funny that you mention arrays, which are by design not type-safe in either Java or C#.  But I'm not saying that these languages aren't designed to catch some errors that are possible in C++.  I'm saying that they are advertised as "safe", "no possibility of memory leaks", etc. and many programmers have bought into these lies and not learned how to deal with critical low-level issues.

Comment: @Ben ... Exactly how are arrays not type safe in Java or C#? Memory "leaks" can happen in any GC language, not just Java or C# -- but there's a difference between memory leaks and loose reference graphs. If you want to call that a lie, you might as well be the guy who sued a lawn mower manufacturer for a lost finger because he shoved his hand down the exhaust. I don't remember MS or Java ever saying either language is "safe" or "no memory leaks" as in safe from bugs; they're "safe" as in, you don't need sandboxing to ensure that code won't maliciously access other things in your processes.

Comment: @Rei: In a type-safe language, arrays would not be covariant, yet both Java and C# allow `object[] x = new string[1];`.  And the C# and Java communities (which are not solely composed of MS or Sun/Oracle employees) very much claim that garbage collection prevents memory leaks.  Look at any of the C++ vs C# or C++ vs Java questions on stackexchange to see that.  Garbage collection isn't bad, the fact that many programmers in GC languages aren't taught to (and don't feel the need to) properly manage object lifetimes is bad.

Comment: @Ben Like I said, there are obviously languages that are more strict (e.g. Haskell), but saying covariance/contravariance makes the language (or even arrays) not type-safe is a polarized overstatement. C# and Java do in many ways encourage beginners, and whether or not beginners should be encouraged is a philosophical question that I don't have an answer for -- but there's a difference between encouraging beginners and encouraging bad designs. Languages are supposed to prevent good programmers from making clumsy mistakes; they're not supposed to weed out bad programmers. That's HR's job.

Comment: @Rei: I think we're essentially in agreement then.  These language features don't make it more difficult for mediocre programmers to make bad designs, which was what I said in my original comment.  The problem is that while the language may make it easier for a good programmer to find bugs, the culture that has grown up around the language leads to an "anyone can do it, because the language is safe" attitude rather than encouraging programmers to become better by understanding issues of typing and resource lifetimes.

Comment: And the mob of mediocre programmers drive down the pay when working with such languages, which causes many of the best programmers to work in other languages where the barriers to entry are higher.

Comment: @Ben That's true. I do tell beginners to learn C as well as a mainstream high-level language (C#/Java/Python) and preferably also a functional language for that reason.

Answer (score 12):

It isn't so much that OOP is enforced, as that an OOP framework is enforced.  It's possible to write procedural programs in Java, although it's easier if they're only one file.

The advantage is uniformity.  There are several different types of functions and data in C++, and this does cause some problems and confusion sometimes, and at the very least is more to learn.  With Java, you've got member functions (class or object based) and similar data, and that's it.

This is intended to make Java easier to read and write, by specializing the language somewhat.

Comment: If that's the motivation, perhaps the language shouldn't have static methods. What's easier to read, `class XyzUtil { static T doStuff(...) { ... } }` and then `XyzUtil.doStuff` or simply `T doStuff(...) { ... }` and then `doStuff()`? If you want to write procedural code (and sometimes that's really the best way, and more often than you'd think it's a valid approach), Java etc. only add cruft, not simplicity.

Comment: @delnan: It's not about how easy it is to read a single function. It's about how easy it is to understand your overall design.

Comment: @Billy: In which case the language is out of play - as already noted, even Java and C# can do little more than enfore classes-based code organization, not decent - let alone sound, OOPy - design.

Comment: @delnan: You can write garbage code in any language. However, with some language features are easy to shoot yourself in the foot. (I'm not defending the decision, I'm saying that David's answer is correct; that is the thinking behind the language design in that manner. Whether or not you agree with the language designers is a whole different matter.)

Comment: But if it's under a meaningful package namespace, part of a class with a meaningful name, with a meaningful name for the static class method itself--it can be quite elegant and self-explanatory. It's when you take a look around how badly types and utility classes are designed and organized that you think almost any rubbish can pass, as long as it's legal.

Comment: @Billy: If I accepted this as the reasoning, I'd assume that the language designers (1) didn't realize that you can write garbage code in any language, and/or (2) though non-object oriented programming is "easy to shoot yourself in the foot with", and/ or (3) thought the language's users are too stupid to do any OOP without being forced into writing out the letters `class`...

Answer (score 9):

Could be "they thought it was a good idea at the time", i.e. having no free functions.  10-15 years ago the development world was excited by "Object Oriented" (just as they all seem to be excited by "Agile" right now).

Even so, I am not sure if every class should derive from Object, but without generics where you need to cast all the time, it does help and it might be the practicality that the VM they built at the time was able to handle it better.

Microsoft's MFC had a concept of CObject too at the top of a big hierarchy.

Comment: The CLR supports non class methods. (They're not accessible in C# except through delegates, but they're first class in C++/CLI)

Comment: @ Billy ONeal: Right - in fact the only language shipped with VS that does not support free fuctions is C#. The others (VB, F#, C++/CLI) do.

Comment: It still is a pretty good idea, it's just not omnipotent.

Comment: Anything more complex than a hello world benefits from OO design.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the most [horrible examples](http://blog.workingsoftware.se/2010/11/sometimes-rewrite-is-only-option.html) of crappy code I've seen is written in Java or C#. I've seen some bad stuff in less strict languages, but it's **nothing** compared to the absolute horrors of staring into the abyss of 1.000.000 lines of copy-pasted static ball-of-mud C# code.

I don't know why that is, but my guess is because it's easier, even possible, to just keep adding more and more (and more...) code in Java/C#, safe in the knowledge that the compiler will tell you when your syntax is wrong. Unfortunately it doesn't tell you when your design is wrong.

I'm not saying Java/C# is bad or anything, quite the opposite. It's just that all this helping, enforcing type-safety makes it possible to mess things up far more than in more flexible, non-enforcing languages.

So I can't really say this "enforcing" policy has improved code quality overall. It has improved the *amount* of code though, that's for sure.

Comment: Unfortunately a by-product of Java's commendable aim of simplicity in their design and syntax made it very easy to learn at a level where you can wreak havoc without the tinyest ounce of understanding. Nobody would do such a thing in assembly for example, because you wouldn't get anywhere without understanding the ins and outs of it.

Comment: @biziclop: Are you suggesting that there's no such thing as badly written assembly?  You can write bad code in *any* language.

Comment: no, he (if I understand him correctly) states that it's easier to write bad code in Java that actually compiles and is functionally correct compared to doing the same in Assembler. Thus bad Assembler code is less likely to end up in the maintenance queue, as it never reaches production.

Comment: Java and C# are easier to learn than C++ therefore attracts weaker programmers.

Comment: @Ant No, it's just that bad assembly code is bad in a different way. The area between something that appears to work and something that works is pretty narrow in assembly compared to the massive rift in Java.

Comment: @CashCow Let's face it, it really isn't. It's easier to learn Java to a level where you can self-destruct, but actually learning the language takes just as long as C++ (obviously without the hassle of different language flavours).

Comment: There's lots of poor Java about. But compared to C it is absolute bliss.

Comment: Employer: "I have some very poorly written C++ and some very poorly written C#. Which do you want to work on?". No brainer, give me the C#

Comment: +1 for pointing out that compilers won't warn you about broken design. So much people out there live by the rule: if it compiles, it just gotta work...

Comment: Bad code is language-agnostic.

Comment: you haven't seen much VB3,4,5,6 or Microsoft Access code then have you?

Answer (score 4):

C# 2.0 added support for `static` classes when it came out 6-7 years ago. That turns a class into a "module" (or "namespace" depending on your choice of jargon) containing nothing but static methods and fields, effectively allowing you to enforce non-OOP style type definition and consumption.

OOP is often encouraged, but it's certainly not enforced. You'd be surprised how much of the .NET libraries are implemented as static classes.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people think that OOP is the best way to write code.  They're either right, wrong, or its open for opinion/debate...doesn't matter.  Those that wrote Java/C# obviously believe the first.

It's easier to enforce OOP as a coding standard if the language itself imposes it.  This is also why languages like Java force you to do other things too, like one public class per file.

They do have somewhat of a point there.  It's hard to get people to do things the way you want.  Give them too much freedom and they do it their way and hope it makes it through review.  If the tools themselves force them into a certain way of doing things then you don't have to argue and/or get team consensus (which everyone promptly ignores anyway).

On the other hand, I never really agreed with anything Java enforced.  For one, there are exceptions to every rule and Java simply doesn't provide for that.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't enforced, after all, as the saying goes: a real developer can write FORTRAN code in any language.

But I have to admit, I don't understand the gist of the question. Well, why not? There are so many languages out there, so Gosling and his friends set out to create one that is based on classes and objects only (okay, and a few primitive types). The idea wasn't entirely groundbreaking, but they also wanted readability, C-like syntax and solid, abstract foundations.

Every lagnuage represents a trade-off between freedom and strict enforcement of a set of principles that help avoid errors. Assembly gives you total freedom and also every possible opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot. Ada was designed to give you very little freedom but fewer opportunities of self-destruction too. One isn't intrinsically better than the other.

Java is just a language leaning towards the stricter end of the spectrum, stricter than C++ but not plunging into the true depths of strong typisation.

C# is somewhat easier to explain, it was Microsoft's reply to the popularity of Java (and their failed attempts to sneak proprietary classes into their implementation of the applet framework :)).

Answer (score 3):

To fulfill the buzzword-compliance requirement.

(This is only partly meant as a joke, but it's true).

These languages are aimed at businesses, and the average decision maker in BigCorporation has no understanding of programming techniques, but he reads everywhere that OOP is the future.

At least, this used to be true 5-15 years ago.

Nowadays, a lot more products are being produced by startups rather than big corporations, so Java and C# ended up losing (in a way). Because they aimed to please the clueless middle manager, the more technical and hackery types of people went on to use different technologies (php, ruby, python, and more recently: node.js).

Comment: It's certainly how it felt at the time with Java. C# on the other hand seemed a legitimate replacement for the old COM system moving to .NET and replacing VB as the "native" language of the system, albeit it was somewhat aimed at being Java-like as Microsoft were prevented from adding their own specifics to Java.

Comment: Honestly, if you've looked at the history of Java, it's all about being a great little language. It is clearly a success in many, many domains.

Answer (score 3):

C++ was built (originally) on top of C, which is procedural. C++ programs still have a 'main' function as the entry-point of a program, which is a procedural legacy.

JavaScript is object-oriented, but is based on the prototype-and-delegation model rather than a class-and-inheritance model (these models are functionally equivalent and equally valid). The OO framework within JavaScript is implicit. Just because you can write

```
<script> var i=21*15; </script>
```

does not mean you are actually using procedural code; under the hood you have implicitly created an anonymous method belonging to the Document object [caveat: I'm guessing based on debugging the DOM; JavaScript experts please correct]

Java and C# were design to be object-oriented using the class-and-inheritance model, hence every program must have a (static) class and Main entry point. Beyond that, though, you are free to be as procedural as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't why do these languages support OOP so much as why they disallow OOP. In particular, I guess that means why they don't allow bare functions that aren't a member of any class.

It seems like the simplest answer is that supporting that would make those languages *more* complex (consider that things like namespaces and overload resolution would have to be able to handle bare functions and those features are already complex) in return for little benefit: you can always just do procedural programming using static functions. What real benefit would non-class functions give you?

Comment: Take a look at Python which is way simpler than C#, object-oriented top to bottom, and still allows bare functions and everything (e.g. methods) is first-class. Of course, it's easier to achieve in a fully dynamic language.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't about "forcing" things. It's merely that *some* solutions can be expressed purely in OO concepts, so the language provides only OO concepts.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess, but one reason *might* be that it makes IDE magic like IntelliSense easier/more helpful. In C++ every function of the C standard library is in the global namespace. Every C++ standard library class and function is in the `std` namespace. And many C++ programs I've worked on also put everything in the global namespace (or used `using namespace XYZ` at the beginning of every file). So if you press Ctrl-Space somewhere in a file, you get a *very* long list of every global function. In C#, all static functions like `Math.Sin` or `Buffer.BlockCopy` are contained in a namespace. So all you get when you press Ctrl-Space are a few classes like `Math`, `Buffer`, ...

Comment: C++ intellisense has its problems because of header files which is different from import package in Java and whatever the C# version is, because import package gives you access to the class but does not bring in any other baggage in with it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others. It isn't!

If you want to know why it is (or nearly is), then look at Eiffel. It is well worth a look at; you can learn Eiffel quicker than C# or Java.

You will finally understand OO, Design by contract, Inheritance, C# properties, and much more.

Answer (score 1):

A language is just an abstraction above the assembly code. The choice of abstraction is simply there to help you solve a problem ( making targeted tasks easier to get right, and certain problems harder to get wrong ).

They had to pick an abstraction. And as I see it ( ignoring all the business reasons ) C# was the conceptual abstraction over C++ which was the abstraction over C except with classes ( OO ). C# simply tried to re-enforce the OO model, and solve problems like memory leaking and abstracting away some of the low level complexities.

If it is not suitable for your problem domain, then simply pick the appropriate language with the best abstraction for you problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

One point which hasn't been mentioned is that in many garbage-collection-based object-oriented framework, it is absolutely 100% imperative that the system know the whereabouts of every single object reference--not just every object, but every reference as well--at any time when garbage collection may occur; if there is any thread `Th` in which the system doesn't know the whereabouts of every single object reference and garbage-collection becomes necessary, all other threads must wait for thread `Th` to reach a point where the system knows where all its object references are.

The above requirement is much stricter than anything which exists for C or C++.  In C or C++, one can construct a union which combines an integer numeric type with a pointer, and provided the code keeps track of whether the thing holds an integer or a pointer, it won't matter whether the runtime framework can tell what type the thing is.  Such an approach wouldn't work in a garbage-collected language.  If interpreting the content of a union as a pointer would reference an object which is being relocated, then it's absolutely imperative that the content of the union be updated to hold the new address if the last thing stored there was a pointer, but it's equally imperative that it be left alone if it's supposed to be holding an integer.  There's simply nothing the runtime can do safely if it can't require object-references be stored in storage locations of object-reference type and nowhere else.

Comment: Actually, there are conservative approaches to GC where everything that “looks like” a pointer is considered one. Note that there *are* working GCs for C++ and similar languages. Furthermore, C# actually allows you to lay out structures in such a way that references are aliased, via `StructLayout`, so the same applies here. Furthermore, I don’t see how this addresses the (admittedly, misguided) question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: A major advantage of using managed garbage-collected storage as the primary persistent storage medium is that allocating things from a contiguous block of free space is much cheaper than allocating from a fragmented collection of free spaces.  Such an advantage is only available, however, if every heap block is relocatable.  One could allow heap blocks to be relocatable in a non-reference-tracking system by using memory handles rather than pointers; such an approach was used in the 68000-based Macintosh system.  I guess a pessimistic GC could work with something like that.

Comment: As for `StructLayout`, I thought overlapping reference types and value types types was forbidden.  Was I mistaken?  With regard to answering your question, the requirement that the framework know about all heap object references imposes significant constraints upon the language design which are not present in other languages like "raw" C++; I would aver that many of the "OO-enforcing" characteristics of C# and Java result from those constraints.